# Unregister to an event using WithEvents declaration

Tags: vb.net

When using the WithEvents declaration instead of AddHanlder, what is the corresponding code to unregister (removeHandler) to an Event? Is this simply to set that WithEvents variable to Nothing?  Is this enough (Framework wise)?

Comment: You can't unregistered the statically bind events.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: @AVD : Why do you tell it as a comment? Is this an answer? Do you mean that the 2 objects are linked forever?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I have a form that I only show for a short while and then it goes away, but it subscribes to my main domain model to get updates about changes. I might have code like this:

```
Private WithEvents _model As WeatherModel

Public Sub New(model As WeatherModel)
   _model = model
End Sub

Private Sub WeatherModel_Update(sender As Object, e As WeatherUpdateEventArgs) _
  Handles _model.WeatherUpdate

  'Handle updated weather conditions
End Sub
```

Since the model I have a reference to will out-live me, if I don't unsubscribe my event handler, it'll cause this form to not be garbage collected. In that case, I'd want to make sure I do `_model = Nothing` in my `FormClosing` event-handler.

In the case that both the form and the `WithEvents` object have the same lifetime (i.e. go out of scope at the same time) or exist for the entire lifetime of the application, you don't need to worry about it.